# Spring Boot Consider switching to 'HttpSecurity' Lambda DSL syntax

Tags: java, spring-boot

My code is here. new AuthEntryPoint() code error to Consider switching to 'HttpSecurity' Lambda DSL syntax. How can i solved. pls help me

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
 
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {
 
  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable();
 
    http.httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(new AuthEntryPoint());
        
    http.authorizeHttpRequests()
            .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/1.0/auth").authenticated()
            .and()
            .authorizeHttpRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
 
    http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
 
    return http.build();
  }
 
  @Bean
  public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
  }
}
```

i try google bard and chatgbt :(

Comment: Please post the exact text of the error, and explain what you were/are wanting the code to do.

Answer (score 3):

Rewrite the above code similar to this and there will be no need of `.and()`

```
http.cors(cors -> cors.disable()).csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
        .authorizeHttpRequests(authorizeRequests -> 
             authorizeRequests.antMatchers("/admins-only/**").hasAuthority(ADMIN)
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated());
```

Similarly, you can try for the different configurations you already have.

If you want specifically for authEntryPoint

```
http.httpBasic(withDefaults()).authenticationEntryPoint(AuthEntryPoint::new)
```

Comment: @Burak Demirer I don't that could be an error, probably a warning if am not wrong or it should be a report by sonar

Comment: I don't think* that it*

Answer (score 2):

your configuration style is still valid and supported. This is a warning from your IDE, not an error message. Adding lambdas was included in [Spring Security 5.2](https://spring.io/blog/2019/11/21/spring-security-lambda-dsl) release and is intended to provide more flexibility, but their usage is optional.

As in the documentation:

> The Lambda DSL was created to accomplish to following goals:
>
> - Automatic indentation makes the configuration more readable.
> - The is no need to chain configuration options using .and().
> - The Spring Security DSL has a similar configuration style to other Spring DSLs such as Spring Integration and Spring Cloud Gateway.

Check the article **[Spring Security - Lambda DSL](https://spring.io/blog/2019/11/21/spring-security-lambda-dsl)** in Spring Blog for more information.